# Lock table redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

how can I do a real LOCK of a table when inserting in redshift, I think it's like that but I'm not sure and aws documentation as always zero input

```
begin;lock table sku_stocks;insert into sku_stocks select facility_alias_id, facility_name, CAST( item_name AS bigint), description, CAST( prod_type AS smallint ), total_available, total_allocated from tp_sku_stocks;
```

Comment: Does it work? Did you add an `UNLOCK` and `commit` at the end?

Comment: yes, at least it doesn't send me an error, but I don't know if it's because it was applied or because it really was like a select current_date, that I want to know which is the right way

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? If it worked, what is the issue?

Comment: my question is to know if that query is the right way to do it because the documentation is not very clear and I don't know if I'm making queries that do nothing and the insertion is done without that blockage or if it's okay

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LOCK` has a [documented behavior](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LOCK.html): it obtains an exclusive lock on the table, so that no other session or transaction can do *anything* to the table.

If you wish to verify this behavior, here's how you can do it:

1. Open a connection to the database and invoke the `begin` and `lock` commands against your test table.
2. Open a *second* connection to the database, and attempt to do a `select` against that table.
3. Wait until either the select returns or your are convinced that `LOCK` behaves as documented.
4. Execute a `rollback` in the first session, so that you're not permanently locking the table.

**Update**

Based on your comments, I think you have a misunderstanding of how transactions work:

- When you start a transaction, Redshift assigns a transaction ID, and marks every row that was changed by that transaction.
- SELECTs that read a table while it is being updated in a transaction will see a "snapshot of the data that has already been committed" (quote from above link), not the rows that are being updated inside the transaction.
- INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE that try to update a table that is being updated by a transaction will block until the transaction completes (see [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_write_readwrite.html), and note that this behavior is somewhat different than you would see from, say, MySQL).
- When you commit/rollback a transaction, any *new* SELECTs will use the updated data. Any SELECTs that were started during the transaction will continue to use the old data.

Given these rules, there's almost no reason for an explicit LOCK statement. Your example update, *without the LOCK,* will put a write-lock on the table being updated (so guaranteeing that no other query can update it at the same time), and will use a snapshot of the table that it's reading.

If you *do* use a LOCK, you will block any query that tries to SELECT from the table during the update. You may *think* this is what you want, to ensure that your users only see the latest data, but consider this any SELECTs that were started prior to the update will still see the old data.

The *only* reason that I would use a LOCK statement is if you need to maintain consistency between a group of tables (well, also if you're getting into deadlocks, but you don't indicate that):

```
begin;
lock TABLE1;
lock TABLE2;
lock TABLE3;
copy TABLE1 from ...
update TABLE2 select ... from TABLE1
update TABLE3 select ... from TABLE2
commit;
```

In this case, you ensure that TABLE1, TABLE2, and TABLE3 will always remain consistent: queries against any of them will show the same information. Beware, however, that SELECTS that started before the lock will succeed, and show data prior to any of the updates. And SELECTs that start *during* the transaction won't actually execute until the transaction completes. Your users may not like that if it happens in the middle of their workday.

Comment: excuse me, my question is to validate the above query if the LOCK is well applied, I need to do that blocking in the insertion since the aws documentation does not provide much as usual ( I know that training is your business)

Comment: @FabiánFuentealba - Sorry, I really don't understand what you're asking. If you need to validate the behavior of `LOCK`, then use the steps that I gave above. If you need to do something else, please try to explain _exactly_ what you're trying to accomplish, with examples of what you expect to see or not see as a result. If you feel that the documentation is unclear, please edit your question and quote the part that that is unclear to you.

Comment: I also don't understand the "training is your business" comment. For what it's worth, I don't work for AWS.

Comment: sorry the "training is your business" was for AWS, I'm sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: sorry, you as redshift experts, i need to be validated if this is the correct way to lock a table to make an insert and that users can't make select and even less another insert, it's understood, that's why i need you to look at the query above and tell me if it's ok or really the lock command is dancing alone... it's understood ... i need to block the table "tp_sku_stocks" to insert data